Legendre polynomials: prove that $P'_{n+1}(x) - P'_{n-1}(x) = (2n+1)P_{n}(x)$ without generating function
I'm trying to prove some identities involving Legendre polynomials without using the generating function. I've a problem with this one:
$P'_{n+1}(x) - P'_{n-1}(x) = (2n+1)P_{n}(x)$.
My tools are just the Rodrigues formula $P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^nn!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}((x^2-1)^n)$, and the recursion formula
$nP_{n}-(2n-1)xP_{n-1}(x) + (n-1)P_{n-2}(x)=0$.
I keep getting $x$ factors from recursion formula or the derivative that I can't cancel so i don't find a good way to prove the statement. Can you please give me some hints?

Try Mathematical Induction.

What do you get when you substitute the recursion formulas for $P_{n+1}, P_{n}, P_{n-1}$ into $P'{n+1} (x)- P'{n-1}(x) - (2n+1) P_n(x)$?

I'm really sorry but I keep not get it. Those $x$ factors pops out everywhere and I don't know how to get rid of them. I've tried to take the derivative of the recusion formula, substitute into it and even an explicit use of the Rodrigues formula. I always come to a point where the RHS of the equations match but the LHS is a complete mess...

because
$$P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^nn!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}((x^2-1)^n)$$
then
$$P_{n+1}'(x) = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}\frac{d}{dx}((x^2-1)^{n+1})=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}(n+1)!}\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}[2(n+1)(x^2-1)^{n-1}(x^2-1+2nx^2)]$$
and
$$P_{n-1}'(x) = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\frac{d}{dx}((x^2-1)^{n-1})=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}((x^2-1)^{n-1})$$
so
$$P'_{n+1}-P'_{n-1}=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}((x^2-1)^{n-1})[\frac{1}{2n}(x^2-1+2nx^2)-1]=\frac{1}{2^nn!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^{n}(2n+1)$$
i.e.
$$P'_{n+1}-P'_{n-1}=(2n+1)P_n$$

Everything is clear, thanks a lot.
